# Entity's primary key field is set to 0 instead of null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a Person entity type like so:

```
public partial class Person
{    
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public byte Gender { get; set; }
    public string IDNumber { get; set; }
}
```

When I create a new Person for the purpose of saving him to the db, the primary key, PersonID, is set to 0, instead of null.

the code:

```
var theNewGuy = new MyEntities.Person();
```

right after this line, theNewGuy.PersonID = 0. The question is, how would I tell it to insert a new Person and assign it the next available primary key? Obviously, I don't want it to be 0, yet there is already a Person in the db with PersonID = 0;

The save code:

```
Velo.People.Add(theNewGuy);
Velo.SaveChanges();//throws error
```

Exception thrown: 
**Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_PERSON'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Person'. The duplicate key value is (0).
The statement has been terminated.**

Comment: Is `PersonID` annotated as an identity in your data model?

Comment: Nope. It's probably as easy as that, I'll change and let you know.

Comment: Seeing as it's a `partial` class.. What's in the rest of the class's implementation? Perhaps it conflicts somehow with the code you posted?

Comment: Why not make the PersonId as autoIncrement and Unique?, it will serve purpose I think.

Comment: If possible, please give us the codes for saving theNewGuy to the DB. Also, please give us the exception thrown, if any. Thank you.

Comment: updated with code and exception

Comment: If you could - add DDL for database table creation - maybe there is something messed up there - like missing definition of PK or autoincrementation? Easiest mistakes are sometimes hardest to spot

Answer (score 5):

Primary keys cannot be Null. A PK must be unique, and Null isn't. Also, `int` is not a nullable type, so it's default value is 0.

EntityFramework should be able to figure out that `PersonID` is `Person`'s key, but just in case try sticking the `[Key]` attribute on there. Additionally, you could force it to be an `auto increment` column by adding the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute to your `PersonID` property.

Answer (score 1):

Since `PersonID` is `int` it never can be `null`. Thus `Entity Framework` assigns `0` as default value. But no worries - if you will add such newly created Entity to database, everything will be fine - it will be saved, given new `PersonID` based on what's already in database, and entity in memory will be refreshed to reflect the new id given by database.

Comment: That's the way it's supposed to work, and how it has worked for me for almost half a decade. however, I get the following SQL exception: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_PERSON'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Person'. The duplicate key value is (0).
The statement has been terminated." Which is why I'm here, begging for help.

Comment: You might want to include this error message into your question to avoid confusion. Interesting, never had this issue. You're using normal `EF` or `Code first`?

Comment: DB First like the Lord intended ;)

Comment: Just to make sure, is your PK column defined as `auto increment`?

Comment: Yes. auto incremented primary key. I think the problem is that there is a record with id = 0. Int PK's usually start at 1, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: EF shouldn't care. My money is on EF not recognizing the property as the key column and/or auto increment. Check my answer for the ID generation option attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you define public int? PersonID { get; set; } (using ? in the type of object) yo can use null as value.

However, how it has been commented, a primary key it would not be null, but perhaps in you particular case in an itermediate state is can be useful.

If you are creating your entity model from a database, as a primary key it would not be null, in the design of the database you can't set this field as nullable, so you must add the "?" modified manually.

Comment: It's a possibility. My problem is that I want to fix the problem, not simply put some duct tape on it. But your answer definitely has merit, thank you.